# What is the difference between enitityManager.find and entityManager.createQuery?

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, persistence, ejb-3.0

Ok, I was using EJB 3.0 with hibernate, we dropped our .ear file into Easy-Beans 1.0.1 (with Hibernate) deploy directory embedded into Apache Tomcat 6.0.18.
So my database had to persist things like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="AUTHOR")
public class Author implements Serializable {

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Fields
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "A_ID", unique=true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;

@Column (name = "A_NAME", unique = false, nullable = false)
private String name;

@Column (name = "A_LASTNAME", unique = false, nullable = false)
private String lastname;

@OneToMany(cascade = {ALL}, fetch = EAGER, mappedBy = "author")
private Set<BookAuthor> bookAuthors = new HashSet<BookAuthor>();

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (this == o) return true;
      if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

      Author author = (Author) o;

      if (id != null ? !id.equals(author.id) : author.id != null) return false;

      return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
      return id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
  }  
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK" )
public class Book implements Serializable {
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Fields
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Id
@GeneratedValue (strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "B_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer bid;

@Column(name = "B_YEAR", unique = false, nullable = true)
private Integer year;

@Column(name = "B_ISBN", unique = false, nullable = false)
private String isbn;

@Column(name = "B_TITLE", unique = false, nullable = false)
private String title;

@OneToMany(cascade = {ALL}, fetch = EAGER, mappedBy = "book")
private Set<BookAuthor> bookAuthors = new HashSet<BookAuthor>();

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Book book = (Book) o;

    if (isbn != null ? !isbn.equals(book.isbn) : book.isbn != null) return false;
    if (bid != null ? !kid.equals(book.bid) : book.bid != null) return false;

    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = bid != null ? bid.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (isbn != null ? isbn.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
  }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOK_AUTHOR")
public class BookAuthor implements Serializable {

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // Fields
  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "BA_ID", unique=true, nullable = false)
  private Integer id;

  @Column(name = "BA_ROLE", unique = false, nullable = true)
  private String role;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn (name = "A_ID", referencedColumnName = "A_ID", nullable = false)
  private Author author;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn (name = "B_ID", referencedColumnName = "B_ID", nullable = false)
  private Book book;

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    BookAuthor that = (BookAuthor) o;

    if (auhtor != null ? !author.equals(that.author) : that.author != null) return false;
    if (book != null ? !book.equals(that.book) : that.book!= null) return false;
    if (id != null ? !id.equals(that.id) : that.id != null) return false;

    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (author != null ? author.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (book != null ? book.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
  }

}
```

So when removing items I had an entity bean that went something like this:

```
@Stateless
@Local(DeleteBookAuthor.class)
public class DeleteBookAuthorBean implements DeleteBookAuthor
{

   @PersistenceContext(unitName="Library")
   protected EntityManager em;

   @Override
   public void removeById(Integer id) {
      try{

        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT ba FROM BookAuthor ba WHERE id = ?1");
        q.setParameter(1,id);

        BookAuthor ba = (BookAuthor) q.getSingleResult();

        ba.getAuthor().getBookAuthors().remove(ba);
        ba.getBook().getBookAuthors().remove(ba);

        em.remove(ba);
      }catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Unfortunatelly, when my Servlet calls this bean it returns a "deleted entity passed to persist" exception; However changing the lines:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT ba FROM BookAuthor ba WHERE id = ?1");
q.setParameter(1,id);        
BookAuthor ba = (BookAuthor) q.getSingleResult();
```

to

```
BookAuthor ba = em.find(BookAuthor.class, id)
```

makes the problem go away. The question I ask is why? In a similar situation I used `em.createQuery` to retrieve and delete muliple entities and it worked without a hitch. So why won't it work now?

UPDATE: Calling 
`Query q=...` and then removing the BookAuthors removes the `BookAuthors` from `Books` but not from the `Authors`. In second case it is removed from both sets. Both `ba` have same hash and return `true` when compared using `baQuery.equals(baFind)` .

Any clarifications why two functions would return same object but calling `remove` would behave differently depending on whether `query`/`find` is called?

Comment: I like these names - Biblioteka, Knjiga :-)

Comment: Serbian names, which means that some where left untranslated :o So, you're from Ukraine. Makes sense. BTW thanks for heads up.

Comment: Anyway - what does this line mean: `em.remove(ak);`, where did you get `ak` variable? Is this a typo and you meant `ba`?

Comment: Yeah (AutorKnjige ak -> BookAuthor ba). Good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it's related to the lack of `equals()`/`hashCode()` in `BookAuthor`. If so, it looks like in the case of query you have several different instances of `BookAuthor` with the same state, so they are not removed from the corresponding sets in `Author` and `Book`.

Comment: `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` exist in original classes as well as getters/setters/constructor. I didn't consider them important for review so I skip them. `equals` and `hashCode` only compare their keys. So in Author equals only compares id.

Comment: @Daniel: Anyways, are you sure that `BookAuthor` is actually removed from the sets?

Comment: No, in first case it is not removed from sets :/ In the second it is.

Comment: @Daniel: I see you compare classes as `getClass() != o.getClass()`. It may fail if one of the classes is a lazy-loading proxy.

Comment: Would `instanceof` help in that case?

Comment: generally it is considered a bad practice to use IDs in equals and hash code - what if your object is not attached to the session and, therefore, IDs are 0 or null? I always use "natural" keys. In case of `Author` this would be the combination of `name` and `lastName`. See this question for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, you can try something like `o instanceof BookAuthor`, however it may cause problems if you have inheritence hierarchies with `BookAuthor`.

Comment: @denis_k: Thanks, I didn't know that. since this was homework it was suggested to us to use ID in equals in order to make sure that object equality = entity equality. On another note, natural keys are harder to implement in EJB and in case of Author there are cases in RL when different people have same last/first name. @axtavt: Ok, I'll try that later this evening. `BookAuthor` really isn't inherited so there should be no problem.

Comment: @axtavt: `instanceof` doesn't seem to work. The problem remains. All my entity beans are independent but it still fails to removes `BookAuthor` in first case for whatever reason. Still thanks for helping.

Comment: Axtavt, your help has been much appreciated, so I'm rewarding you with this answer even though the problem has not been completely clarified.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, `Query.getSingleResult()` flushes the session under some circumstances, and  I'm not sure about`EntityManager.find()`. I would follow axtavt's suggestion and doublecheck if your entity is removed from sets properly. And also I would call this statement before `em.remove(ba);` to make sure your `ba` object was re-attached to the session:

```
ba = em.merge(ba);
```